# Voice notifications for Google Calendar on Windows

Tags: windows, calendar, google-apps, notification

I'm attempting to find an application that will allow voice notifications for Google Calendar on Microsoft Windows operating systems. I've found some Android apps that can do this, but I still haven't found a Windows application for it.

In other words: are there any applications that can provide text to speech notifications for Windows at the time when the events are scheduled?

Answer (score 1):

[Checker Plus for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-google-c/hkhggnncdpfibdhinjiegagmopldibha?hl=en) is able to provide voice notifications for Google Calendar. The voice notifications option can be enabled in the "options" menu for this extension.